# Как скопировать изображение с помощью CopyFile, если имя изображения нам известно?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Как добавить к имени изображения путь, чтобы копировать изображение с помощью `CopyFile`, если имя изображения нам известно?

У нас имеется имя изображения есть двух типов(на выбор):

1. типа `const wchat *image_name = "001.jpg"`
2. типа `const char *image_name = "001.jpg"`

Есть функция:

```
CopyFile(L"\\image_name", L"\\0\\image_name.jpg", true);
```

Мы копируем из корневой папки файл в папку 0, без изменения имени.
Вроде простой случай, но возник затык.

Проблема в том, что в кавычках `image_name` не является переменной. Вопрос в том как добавить информацию о пути в image_name, чтобы было не `"001.jpg"`, а `"\\0\\001.jpg"`

**UPD**

Использовал wcscat. Но значение `p_image` и `pc_image` не меняются.
Вот код:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hf;
hf = FindFirstFile(L"*.jpg", &FindFileData);
if (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  do
  {
    k = 2;

    //CStringW image_name = FindFileData.cFileName;
    //CString myConvertedString = image_name;
    ///*const char* namefile;
    //cout << "Name file";
    //cin >> namefile;*/
    const WCHAR* image_name = FindFileData.cFileName;
    const WCHAR* image_name3 = FindFileData.cFileName;
    _bstr_t b(image_name);
    const char* image_name2 = b;

    init_image(image_name2, k, sty);
    pert1 = template_1(y, x);
    pert2 = template_2(y, x);
    pert3 = template_3(y, x);
    /*  cout << "template 1: = " << pert1 << endl;
    cout << "template 2: = " << pert2 << endl;
    cout << "template 3: = " << pert3 << endl;
    system("pause");
    */
    res = calculation_number(pert1, pert2, pert3);
    if (res == -1)
      cout << "нет распознанных цифр" << endl;
    if (res == 0)
    {
      cout << "Это изображение распознано как 0:" << image_name2 << endl;
      WCHAR *p_image = L"\\";
      WCHAR *pc_image = L"\\0\\";
      wchar_t* wcscat(wchar_t* p_image, const wchar_t* image_name3);
      wchar_t* wcscat(wchar_t* pc_image, const wchar_t* image_name3);
      wcout << p_image << endl;
      wcout << pc_image << endl;

      CopyFile(p_image, pc_image, true);
    }

    //std::wcout << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;

  } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
  FindClose(hf);
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Совершенно не ясно в чем же у вас проблема.

Comment: проблема в том, что в кавычках image_name не является переменной. Вопрос в том как добавить информацию о пути в image_name, чтобы было не "001.jpg", а "\\0\\001.jpg"

Comment: То есть проблема не в копировании, а в склеивании строк? Меняйте вопрос...

Comment: Сейчас изменю, неграмотно задал вопрос

Comment: pc_image указывает на константный кусок памяти со строкой "\0\". Юзай либо pc_image[], либо string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объединение двух строк может решаться через `strcat`/`wcscat` или через оператор объединения строк (`+`) у `std::string`/`std::wstring`.